# Format multiple .csv files simultaneusly using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I'm trying to run a code that formats multiple .csv files within a specific folder at once. In the original data sheet, the rows containing values were spaced apart.

I want to remove the empty rows and extract the numeric values contained within the cells to another adjacent cell.

The code I tried to use works on single sheets, but once I've failed to adapt it to use on multiple files.

```
Sub RunOnAllFilesInFolder()
    Dim folderName As String, eApp As Excel.Application, fileName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, currWs As Worksheet, currWb As Workbook
    Dim fDialog As Object: Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    Set currWb = ActiveWorkbook: Set currWs = ActiveSheet
 
   folderName = "C:\xxxx\test\"
    
    
    'Create a separate Excel process that is invisibile
    Set eApp = New Excel.Application:  eApp.Visible = False
    
    'Search for all files in folder [replace *.* with your pattern e.g. *.xlsx]
    fileName = Dir(folderName & "\*.csv")
    Do While Len(fileName) > 0
        'Update status bar to indicate progress
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing " & folderName & "\" & fileName
 
 
        Set wb = eApp.Workbooks.Open(folderName & "\" & fileName)
        '...
        
        
        
    Dim s As String, i As Long, L As Long, c As String, temp As String, d As String, p As String, v As String
    
    Range("A11").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("A10").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A13").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("A11").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A15").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("A12").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    s = [A9]
    L = Len(s)
    temp = ""
    For i = 1 To L
        c = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If c Like "[0-9]" Then
            temp = temp & c
        Else
            temp = temp & " "
        End If
    Next i

    temp = "'" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(temp)
    temp = Replace(temp, " ", ",")

    [D9] = temp
    
    
    d = [A10]
    L = Len(s)
    temp = ""
    For i = 1 To L
        c = Mid(d, i, 1)
        If c Like "[0-9]" Then
            temp = temp & c
        Else
            temp = temp & " "
        End If
    Next i

    temp = "'" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(temp)
    temp = Replace(temp, " ", ",")

    [D10] = temp
    
    
    
    p = [A11]
    L = Len(s)
    temp = ""
    For i = 1 To L
        c = Mid(p, i, 1)
        If c Like "[0-9]" Then
            temp = temp & c
        Else
            temp = temp & " "
        End If
    Next i

    temp = "'" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(temp)
    temp = Replace(temp, " ", ",")

    [D11] = temp
    
    
    v = [A12]
    L = Len(s)
    temp = ""
    For i = 1 To L
        c = Mid(v, i, 1)
        If c Like "[0-9]" Then
            temp = temp & c
        Else
            temp = temp & " "
        End If
    Next i

    temp = "'" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(temp)
    temp = Replace(temp, " ", ",")

    [D12] = temp
    
    
    
    
        '...
       wb.Close SaveChanges:=True 'Close opened worbook w/o saving, change as needed
       Debug.Print "Processed " & amp; folderName & amp; "\" & amp; fileName
       fileName = Dir()
       
       
    Loop
    eApp.Quit
    Set eApp = Nothing
    'Clear statusbar and notify of macro completion
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    MsgBox "Completed executing macro on all workbooks"
End Sub
```

I've tried to use some code I've found online and it will always run without an error message, but in the end, the files seems to be unaffected. Even after splitting up the task (eg just shifting the data without extracting the numeric values), it still wont work.

Comment: Screenshots of before/after would help here - it's a bit of a slog to guess the layout from your code

Comment: You have `L = Len(s)` for A10, A11, A12 but should be `Len(d)`, `Len(p)`, `Len(s)`. The csv files are opening in a separate Excel process (eApp) so will not be the activesheet for `ActiveSheet.Paste`.

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RunOnAllFilesInFolder()

    Dim wb As Workbook, cel As Range
    Dim folderName As String, fileName As String
    Dim temp As String, sep As String
    Dim regex As Object, m As Object
    Dim n As Long, i As Long, t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    
    folderName = "C:\temp\SO\77460667" ' "C:\xxxx\test\"
    If Right(folderName, 1) <> "\" Then folderName = folderName & "\"
    
    ' pattern for extracting numbers
    Set regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With regex
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "([0-9]+)"
    End With
    
    ' Search for all csv files in folder
    fileName = Dir(folderName & "*.csv")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While Len(fileName) > 0
    
        'Update status bar to indicate progress
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing " & folderName & fileName
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderName & fileName)
        
        ' process sheet
        With wb.Sheets(1)
            .Range("A10") = .Range("A11")
            .Range("A11") = .Range("A13")
            .Range("A12") = .Range("A15")
            .Range("A13,A15").ClearContents
            
             ' extract numbers from A to D
            For Each cel In .Range("A9:A12")
                temp = ""
                sep = ""
                Set m = regex.Execute(cel)
                For i = 1 To m.Count
                    temp = temp & sep & m(i - 1)
                    sep = ", "
                Next
                cel.Offset(, 3) = temp
            Next
        End With
        
        ' close and get next
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True 'Close opened workbook saving changes
        fileName = Dir()
        n = n + 1
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    'Clear statusbar and notify of macro completion
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    MsgBox n & " csv files processed", vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
End Sub
```